# Get price and total of different product and send to Paypal idk iOS

Tags: ios, paypal

I am working on PayPal SDK in iOS. When I pass the total amount of a single product with its total quantity to the payPal SDK, it works perfectly. But if i have more than 1 product in the cart and each product has different amount and quantity, how to pass the total amount to the PayPal. Help me to get out of it. I am calculating and passing price in "EURO" currency format. Thanks in advance.     My code is :-

```
        - (IBAction)paypalButtonForSubmitData:(id)sender  
        {  
            NSDecimalNumber *subTotal;    
            NSArray *items;    
            self.resultText = nil;    
    // Here _arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal is array through which I am getting data from Plist.         
       for (int j=0; j<_arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal.count; j++)   
            {  
                NSMutableDictionary *paypalArrayDataInDictionary=[_arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal objectAtIndex:j];    
// priceDetail is giving me the price of any particular product.  
                NSString *priceDetail=[paypalArrayDataInDictionary objectForKey:@"PRICE"];      
                NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [priceDetail stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"€" withString:@""];  
                NSLog(@"Price=%@",stringWithoutSpaces);  
                PayPalItem *item1=[PayPalItem itemWithName:@"IPHONE" withQuantity:[[paypalArrayDataInDictionary objectForKey:@"STOCK"]intValue] withPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:stringWithoutSpaces] withCurrency:@"EUR" withSku:@"SKU-iPhone6"];    
                items= @[item1];    
                subTotal=[PayPalItem totalPriceForItems:items];    
                NSDecimalNumber *shipping=[[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:@"0,00"];   
                NSDecimalNumber *tax=[[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:@"0,00"];     

                PayPalPaymentDetails *paymentDetails=[PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetailsWithSubtotal:subTotal withShipping:shipping withTax:tax];    
                NSDecimalNumber *total=[[subTotal decimalNumberByAdding:shipping]decimalNumberByAdding:tax];    

                PayPalPayment *payment=[[PayPalPayment alloc]init];    
                payment.amount=total;    
                payment.currencyCode=@"EUR";    
                payment.shortDescription=@"My Payment";    
                payment.items=items;    
                payment.intent = PayPalPaymentIntentSale;    
                payment.paymentDetails=paymentDetails;    
                NSLog(@"Payment=%@",payment);    

                if (!payment.processable)   {    
                    NSLog(@"Error");    
                }  
                // self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards=self.acceptCreditCards;    
                PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController=[[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc]initWithPayment:payment configuration:self.payPalConfig delegate:self];    
                [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:true completion:nil];    
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write code of presenting PaypalViewController out of for loop,

for this you need to declare below code ,

```
PayPalPayment *payment=[[PayPalPayment alloc]init];
```

before starting loop.

Please try below edited code

```
   - (IBAction)paypalButtonForSubmitData:(id)sender  
    {  
        NSDecimalNumber *subTotal;    
        NSArray *items;    
        self.resultText = nil;    
// Here _arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal is array through which I am getting data from Plist.         
   for (int j=0; j<_arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal.count; j++)   
        {  
            NSMutableDictionary *paypalArrayDataInDictionary=[_arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal objectAtIndex:j];    
           // priceDetail is giving me the price of any particular product.  
            NSString *priceDetail=[paypalArrayDataInDictionary objectForKey:@"PRICE"];      
            NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [priceDetail stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"€" withString:@""];  
            NSLog(@"Price=%@",stringWithoutSpaces);  
            PayPalItem *item1=[PayPalItem itemWithName:@"IPHONE" withQuantity:[[paypalArrayDataInDictionary objectForKey:@"STOCK"]intValue] withPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:stringWithoutSpaces] withCurrency:@"EUR" withSku:@"SKU-iPhone6"];    
            items= @[item1];    
        }
            subTotal=[PayPalItem totalPriceForItems:items];    
            NSDecimalNumber *shipping=[[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:@"0,00"];   
            NSDecimalNumber *tax=[[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:@"0,00"];     

            PayPalPaymentDetails *paymentDetails=[PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetailsWithSubtotal:subTotal withShipping:shipping withTax:tax];    
            NSDecimalNumber *total=[[subTotal decimalNumberByAdding:shipping]decimalNumberByAdding:tax];    

            PayPalPayment *payment=[[PayPalPayment alloc]init];    
            payment.amount=total;    
            payment.currencyCode=@"EUR";    
            payment.shortDescription=@"My Payment";    
            payment.items=items;    
            payment.intent = PayPalPaymentIntentSale;    
            payment.paymentDetails=paymentDetails;    
            NSLog(@"Payment=%@",payment);    

            if (!payment.processable)   {    
                NSLog(@"Error");    
            }  
            // self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards=self.acceptCreditCards;    
            PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController=[[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc]initWithPayment:payment configuration:self.payPalConfig delegate:self];    
            [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:true completion:nil];        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is not giving the total price of the product available in the cart (suppose 10 products). How to do this ?

Comment: same as before. Not giving the total price of products.

Comment: Successfully done. Actually I was not adding objects in the array. But thanks for your response.